# Why a "org.hibernate.MappingException: In trying to locate getter for property, Class defined both a get and is variant" error using @Transient?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given the following class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base {

    protected int net;

    int getNet() { return net; }

    void setNet(int value) { net = value; }

    @Transient
    boolean isNet() { return true; }
}
```

I annotated `isNet` as @Transient to resolve the ambiguity and tell JPA to persist using the get and set methods and ignore the is. But I still get this error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."DevCrowd.war#prod": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."DevCrowd.war#prod": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: prod] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: prod] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: In trying to locate getter for property [net], Class [business.state.entity.Base] defined both a `get` [public int business.state.entity.Base.getNet()] and `is` [public boolean business.state.entity.Base.isNet()] variant
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.checkGetAndIsVariants(ReflectHelper.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.verifyNoGetVariantExists(ReflectHelper.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getGetterOrNull(ReflectHelper.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findGetterMethod(ReflectHelper.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessBasicImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessBasicImpl.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyBasicImpl.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:63)
    ... 27 more
```

Where

> org.hibernate.MappingException: In trying to locate getter for
>   property [net], Class Base defined both a `get` and `is` variant

tells me that @Transient didn't resolve the ambiguity for some reason. Why is that? Please ignore that the `isNet` method is stupid. It's a minimal example.

Added from comments:

If I remove the @Transient annotation I get an error

> Ambiguous persistent property methods detected on ...Base; mark one as @Transient : [public int ...getNet()] and [public boolean ....isNet()].

So it's asking me to use this annotation

Comment: Isn't `@Transient` meant to annotate a field only ? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Comment: @Berger First, even if the super old link to EE5 it specifies as either method or field. Same in EE7. Second, if I remove this annotation I get an error `Ambiguous persistent property methods detected on ...Base; mark one as @Transient : [public int ...getNet()] and [public boolean ....isNet()]`. So it's asking me to use this annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in hibernate 5.2.11

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11716

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's your error.

> Caused by: `org.hibernate.MappingException`: In trying to locate getter
>   for property [net], Class [`business.state.entity.Base`] defined both a
>   'get' [`public int business.state.entity.Base.getNet()`] and 'is'
>   [`public boolean business.state.entity.Base.isNet()`] variant

I suspect that `@Transient` tells JPA to ignore the field altogether, but that doesn't resolve the conflict between get and is. It is not telling JPA to ignore the method.

I know you asked us to ignore your non-standard use of is, but I suggest you avoid doing things like this in general. It causes confusion for other developers and, apparently, for JPA as well.

Comment: I added the information in the comments to the question. Based on the error I get I don't think @Transient ignores the whole field because then why would it ask me to resolve the ambiguity by annotating one of the methods?

Comment: I think the solution suggested by the error message is misleading. I think it meant to mark the field as @Transient, so that JPA would not search for getters. I would be surprised if JPA allows you to prefer one getter over another; it expects that only one getter is defined.

Comment: How is it telling me to mark the field when the message explicitly says `mark one as @Transient : [public int ...getNet()] and [public boolean ....isNet()]` ---> Mark one of getNet and isNet Transient. I think it's pretty clear. Also why would JPA not allow me to tell it to ignore a getter which isn't even of the "correct" type? I'm telling it to use `get` and `set` for int and ignore the `is` of boolean. How would it even use a get and set of different types?

Comment: Mark, I understand your frustration. Sometimes, the suggestion made in those error messages are a bit off. However, marking one of the methods with @Transient simply isn't going to solve anything. Your best be is to change "is" to "check" or something similar.

Comment: OK so if I want to report this as a bug who do I report it to? The application server, hibernate, oracle?

Comment: The message is coming from Hibernate. I agree that it is misleading.